# Disable Scrollbars in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'd like to disable all scrollbars in Ace editor, or replace with something more stylish. Can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replacing scrollbars with custom ones would be quite painful.

But you can always hide the editor's scrollbars with this simple (though hacky) CSS:

```
.ace_scrollbar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

On older Ace version:

```
.ace_sb {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use [::-webkit-scrollbar-](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/) and ignore browsers that are stupid enough to not implement it.

Hiding scrollbars is possible, but in a rather hacky way, so if you need to have stylish scrollbars on firefox too, try asking on https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/869